# How can I write iid in an equation in normal letters?

Tags: math-mode, equations, code, letters, italic

I want to write this equation:

`lnpt+1 =ρp lnpt +εp,t+1, ρp ∈(−1,1), εp,t+1 iid N(0,σ2p).`

How can I write the `iid` in normal letters, that they are not `cursive` (not `italic`)?

The code I used so far is:

```
\begin{equation}
\ln{Z_{t+1}}=\rho_{Z}\ln{Z_{t}+\epsilon_{Z,t+1}},   
\quad \rho_{Z}\in(-1,1),\epsilon_{Z,t+1},{iid}{N} (0,\sigma^2_{Z}).
\end{equation}
```

But the `iid` turns out to be `cursive` (`italic`). How can I make it not `cursive` (not `italic`)?

Comment: I'd use `\quad\mathrm{iid}\enspace N(0,\sigma^2_{Z})` or similar

Comment: The comma before `iid` can't be right.

Comment: Off-topic: `\ln` doesn't take an argument. Thus, do replace `\ln{Z_{t+1}}` with `\ln Z_{t+1}`, etc.

Answer (score 8):

I would change `iid` to `\mathrm{iid}` and place it above a "distributed as" symbol, say, `\sim`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for '\overset' macro
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\ln Z_{t+1} = \rho_{Z}\ln Z_{t}+\epsilon_{Z,t+1},   
\quad \rho_{Z}\in(-1,1),\ 
\epsilon^{}_{Z,t+1} \overset{\mathrm{iid}}{\sim} N(0,\sigma^2_{Z})\,.
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try with this:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\ln Z_{t+1}=\rho_{Z}\ln Z_{t}+\epsilon_{Z,t+1},   \quad \rho_{Z}\in(-1,1),\epsilon_{Z,t+1},\text{ iid } N (0,\sigma^2_{Z}).
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

As you don't provide your preamble, I used standard `book` class file...